# Python Parent/Child class method call

Tags: python

Python 2.7.6 on Linux.

I'm using a test class that inherits from a parent.  The parent class holds a number of fields that are common to many child classes, and I need to call the parent `setUp` method to initialize the fields.  Is calling `ParentClass.setUp(self)` the correct way to do this?  Here's a simple example:

```
class RESTTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.protocol = protocol
        self.context = context

class HistoryTest(RESTTest):
    def setUp(self):
        RESTTest.setUp(self)
        self.endpoint = history_endpoint
        self.url = "%s://%s:%s/%s/%s" %(self.protocol, self.host, self.port, self.context, self.endpoint)

    def testMe(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Is this correct?  It seems to work.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You would use `super` for that.

```
super(ChildClass, self).method(args)

class HistoryTest(RESTTest):
    def setUp(self):
        super(HistoryTest, self).method(args)
        ...
```

In Python 3 you may write:

```
class HistoryTest(RESTTest):
    def setUp(self):
        super().method(args)
        ...
```

which is simpler.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods):

> `super()` lets you avoid referring to the base class explicitly, which can be nice. But the main advantage comes with multiple inheritance, where all sorts of [fun stuff](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236275) can happen. See the [standard docs on super](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) if you haven't already.

#### Multiple inheritance

To (try to) answer the question in your comment:

> How do you specify which super method you want to call?

From what I understand of the philosophy of multiple inheritance (in Python), you don't. I mean, `super`, along with the Method Resolution Order (MRO) should do things right and select the appropriate methods. (Yes methods is a plural, see below.)

There are a lot of blog posts / SO answers about this you can find with keywords "*multiple inheritance*", "*diamond*", "*MRO*", "*super*", etc. [This article](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_multiple_inheritance.php) provides a Python 3 example I found surprising and didn't find in other sources:

```
class A:
    def m(self):
        print("m of A called")

class B(A):
    def m(self):
        print("m of B called")
        super().m()

class C(A):
    def m(self):
        print("m of C called")
        super().m()

class D(B,C):
    def m(self):
        print("m of D called")
        super().m()

D().m()

m of D called
m of B called
m of C called
m of A called
```

See? Both `B.m()` and `C.m()` are called thanks to `super`, which seems like the right thing to do considering D inherits from both `B` and `C`.

I suggest you play with this example like I just did. Adding a few `print`s,  you'll see that, when calling `D().m()`, the `super().m()` statement in class `B` itself calls `C.m()`. Whereas, of course, if you call `B().m()` (`B` instance, not `D` instance), only `A.m()` is called. In other words, `super().m()` in `B` is aware of the class of the instance it is dealing with and behaves accordingly.

Using `super` everywhere sounds like the silver bullet, but you need to make sure all classes in the inheritance schema are *cooperative* (another keyword to dig for) and don't break the chain, for instance when expecting additional parameters in child classes.

Comment: OK, so what about multiple inheritance?  How do you specify **which** super `method` you want to call?

Comment: ``super()`` calls the immediate parent class, if the function isn't there, it'll search up the chain.  So if you had ``class Obj(A, B, C):``, the ``super()`` call will look first in A, if it's not there, then B, and so on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance